# How to adapt Canvas for different phone resolutions? Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I want to adapt the canvas for different phone resolutions (1280x800, 854x480, etc.).
On Internet I see that I require to use a component for the Canvas - Canvas Scaler, but for me it is somehow incorrect or I'm choosing the wrong settings.
Actually, I can not find a solution, so I'm here. There are 3 options for screenshots of different resolutions, and somewhere something climbs or moves, although I do not need it! https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODg99.jpg I did it specifically for the resolution of 1280x800 and here everything looks right. And on a resolution of 854x480, a sprite of the board climbs to the side, at 480x320 on top it climbs the same sprite. How to solve this problem? The configuration of my canvas is on the same link. Translated by Google Translater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Canvas needs "overlay" render mode(